# Which parameter type to provide that is IEnumerable and has Count?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics

Oftentimes, providing methods which accept an array could be optimized to accept more generic classes that are both `IEnumerable` and require a `Count` or `Length`.

**Example:**

```
public static T NextObject<T>(this Random random, T[] array)
{
    return array[random.Next(array.Length)];
}
```

Here, I use `Array` to get a specific element, knowing the amount of elements. Which class is optimal for this in a general manner?

- IList
- ICollection - also has `Count`
- *other interface or class or a set of different interfaces?*

I *think*, `IEnumerable` may not be a good idea, because `Count()` can cause side effects on performance if the underlying enumerator is more complex.

Comment: I'd suggest using `ICollection<T>`, but I think it's a bit *opinion based*.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` doesn't have an indexer. I think both this and `Array` as two overloads could *(not sure)* cover all types. I don't think this is opinion based, because the question is basically covering all common types with the least overloads.

Comment: why don't a simple List<T> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need access items by index and count of items in the collection. You also want less additional members in collection/interface

```
                      | IList<T> | ICollection<T> | IEnumerable<T> | T[]
Access by index       |     +    |        -       |        -       |   +
Count of items        |     +    |        +       |        -       |   +
Less unwanted members |     -    |        +       |        +       |   ~
```

As you can see, ICollection and IEnumerable does not fit your needs. I don't see big difference between picking IList or array. IList maybe more lightweight than array, but it has lot of unwanted operations (Add,Remove,Clear) and with array you can use `params` which is often handy.

Comment: Very good visualization! So probably providing an overload with both array and IList would be best... But what if the code is more complex than in the example? Providing just Array and requiring `.ToArray` in the consuming method?

Comment: @bytecode77 probably two overloads with `IList<T>` and `params T[]` would be the most handy option: `ranomd.NextObject(apple, banana, peach)` looks good

Answer (score 0):

Your method should take in the least specific type which satisfies the method's needs. Aim for the least possible coupling possible. Here is the signature for `ICollection`

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Since neither `ICollection<T>` nor `IEnumerable<T>` support indexing, then none will work.

Array is too specific but `List<T>` or `IList<T>` will satisfy your needs since you need access by index. Otherwise, the clients (consumers of the class) will need to cast to the array type.

> But count can cause side effects on performance

`Count()` is an extension method of `System.Linq.Enumerable`. It will attempt to cast to types which support O(1) count like ICollection (Count property). If none are available then it will traverse all items and count them which becomes O(N).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's even *all* collection classes implementing `IEnumerable<T>`. But since it doesn't support random access and using `.Skip` has indeterminable compact on performance, IEnumerable can't be used.

Comment: @bytecode77 sorry your question was about count and length but I now see your code requires random indexing. Edited the answer.